# Ionic Native - AES256 : Error occurred while performing decrypt AES256

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, encryption, aes, ionic-native

I'm having an issue when I try to encrypt and decrypt a string.
I'm using the Native plugin from Ionic.
It might have installed it properly because the encryption works.

Here is my code mostly copy pasted from the example on Ionic docs:

```
this._Pass = "1234";
let encryptedData;

this.aes.encrypt('12345678123456781234567812345678', '1234567812345678', this._Pass)
  .then(res => {
    encryptedData =  res;
    console.log('Encrypted Data: ',res)
  })
  .catch((error: any) => console.error(error));

this.aes.decrypt('12345678123456781234567812345678', '1234567812345678', encryptedData)
  .then(res => console.log('Decrypted Data : ',res))
  .catch((error: any) => console.error(error));
```

Here is my result in the console:

```
[app-scripts] [10:35:31]  console.log: Encrypted Data: UFvt/KMgnx5ULVVqBEyueg==
[app-scripts] [10:35:31]  console.error: Error occurred while performing decrypt
[app-scripts] [10:35:32]  console.log: [object Object]
```

I'm running directly on an Samsung tablet with android 5.0.2

Comment: Hi Charly, 

have you found a solution for this problem? I'm having the same.,.

Comment: Hi @markosca, no apparently it just didn't work at all... I'm using sha256 ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/sha256) instead.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your reply and your suggestion!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? @Charly

Comment: Hi @AliHaider as I said to markosca I've used sha256 ( npmjs.com/package/sha256)